# Why does jquery load not work when mvc httppost is defined?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, http-post

The following configuration works - it loads the Edit view into a div:

**jQuery:**

```
$("#mydiv").load(
    "/Riders/Edit",
    { riderId: 123 },
    function (data) { }
);
```

**RidersController:**

```
Function Edit(ByVal riderId As Integer) As ActionResult
    Return View(_db.Riders.Single(Function(x) x.rider_id = riderId))
End Function
```

But when I add an HttpPost to the controller for Edit, I get an error:

```
<HttpPost()>
Function Edit(ByVal model As Rider) As ActionResult
   'code...
End Function
```

**Error:**

```
POST http://localhost:4693/Riders/Edit 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Now why would I be getting a POST error on a load? I'm sure I'm just missing something in my setup, but I'm not seeing it yet.

Comment: @musefan Yes, both actions are in the controller just as you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing parameters using GET method, so it never finds your controller action if you specify it to be POST. From this link: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/

> If parameters are passed as an object (rather than string), they are
>   passed to the remote url in the POST method.

That would be your solution.

Comment: Bingo! I knew it was something simple like that. I'm pretty sure I've run into that before too. The link was very helpful, thanks!